# Maps Application Error

Tags: android

I am doing a Google MAPS application in android. I have installed the 2 platforms 2.3.3 and 2.1 and corresponding the Google API also.I have got the Google Maps API key.I have Added the permissions in manifest file also.For this application I used  Google API 2.1 for Build SDk and Android 2.1 for MinSDK version.But when I run the project it shows a warning in Console

**Ignoring platform 'android-8': build.prop is missing** .

Also an error on the API KEY I pasted  on the main.xml file ( android:apikey =  ) is

**error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)**

main.xml file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:enabled="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="<MYAPIKEY>" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have no error in Main activity.How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I have hidden your apikey, so others can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API key shouldn't have the `<` and `>` characters in it.

Comment: Thanks  The error is gone. I have one doubt also. will a project work with the Google API 2.1 target